# jQuery ajax method with dataType 'json' incorrectly parsing json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, getjson

I'm having some inexplicable behaviour using jQuery 1.4.2, and I'm beginning to think that it might be a safari problem, not a jQuery one.  Let me explain.

I began simply enough by using .getJSON like this:

```
$.getJSON("/challenge/results", form_data, function(data){
  //I know console.log is bad news, just a simplification.
  console.log('data', data); 
}
```

And the log gave me something along the lines of

```
>locations: Array (1)
```

While I was expecting an array of size 2.  So I had a look at the json in the response:

```
{"locations":
[{"customer_id":2,"editable":true,"id":971,"latitude":43.659208,"longitude":-79.407501,"max_zoom":25,"min_zoom":9,"name":"test"},
{"customer_id":3,"editable":true,"id":974,"latitude":36.746944,"longitude":-107.970899,"max_zoom":25,"min_zoom":9,"name":"test2"}]}
```

I've simplified this considerably for the sake of clarity, but as far as I can tell, the json received is perfectly valid (generated programmatically through rails). [**Update:** JSONLint confirms this hypothesis.]

I was surprised by this, so I converted my request to a $.ajax request to see if there was some subtle difference between them (since then, looking in the source of jQuery I see that $.getJSON simply calls $.ajax).

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"/challenge/results",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: form_data,
        cache:false,
        success: function(data, textStatus){
            console.log("data!", data, textStatus);
        });
```

But alas! The same response:

> locations: Array (1) success

At this point, I must admit - I was getting a bit silly, so I thought I would try something completely bound to fail:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"/challenge/results",
        dataType: 'text',
        data: form_data,
        cache:false,
        success: function(data, textStatus){
            console.log("Parsed:!", $.parseJSON(data), textStatus);
        });
```

Much to my surprise my console read:

> locations: Array (2) success

I was stumped.  At this point I dug in my heels and took a long hard look at the jQuery source (1.4.2).  I suppose unsurprisingly, the ajax function seems not to handle the json parsing itself (although, I must admit, I can't be sure).

I'm totally at a loss for why this could be happening - any help is appreciated.

Comment: what's the JSON look like when it comes back as text?  Formatted the same?

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly as it does when I view the response in the webkit inspector.

Comment: jQuery 1.4.2 parses json the same way you do in your second example: `data = jQuery.parseJSON( data );` - it happens in the httpData function. Try to do `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` in your first example and see if what it outputs - if it doesn't look like what you send, then you probably have malformated json

Comment: You said it may be a safari problem.  Do you get the correct results (Array(2)) from a different browser?

Comment: The plot thickens.  Thanks Martin, that gave me a start.  Instead of your suggestion, I just loaded up a patched version of jquery source, and logged the pre-parse data, the post-parse data, and then the stringified version of the post-parse'd data.  The first two are unsurprising (yeilding what I've seen above), but the stringify brought back the original 2 element array!  It's fair to say I'm mistified. Finally, I tried copying the output (pre-parse) json, and using parseJSON in the console on it - 2 elements.  Same with stringified json. Why would the same function have different behaviour?

Comment: @idbentley: To help you further i'd need access to your code, i'm sure there's a simple explanation for this, one that you can't expose properly in an example... the devil is always in the details.

Comment: I agree, can you post an example link?

Comment: Thanks guys for your help - the problem was with the logging.  Using `debugger` statements made it obvious my problem was elsewhere (as I suspected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Webkit inspector's debugger should be used instead of console logging, which can show the object in a future state.  This was the cause of this problem as the list was being trimmed in code after the `console.log` line, which resulted in the unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I missed something, but I notice that your JSON is an object that has a single property (`"locations"`) with an array as it's value. Have you tried:

```
$.getJSON("/challenge/results", form_data, function(data){
  //I know console.log is bad news, just a simplification.
  console.log('data', data.locations); 
}
```

Comment: That was just a snippit of the object.  Thanks though!

Comment: @idbentley: Ah, sorry, I did misread. Can you post an example link?

Comment: @idbentley: What do you mean by snippit of the object by the way? Did it not show the two array elements?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  The full Object was something like {locations: Array(1), ....}.  The object has more than just locations in it, but that seems to be fine - I'm having the weird behaviour on the locations array.  When I inspect the array using the webkit inspector, it shows 1 location element (specifically, id=971) and omits the other.  I can post an example, but it will probably have to wait till next tuesday.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 // Enables for all serialization
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

// Enables for a single serialization
jQuery.param( stuff, true );

// Enables for a single Ajax requeset
$.ajax({ data: stuff, traditional: true });
```

hey,your problem seems like to be have something to do with the nested param serialization.just as what the jQuery 1.4 release note say:

Query 1.4 adds support for nested param serialization in jQuery.param, using the approach popularized by PHP, and supported by Ruby on Rails. For instance, {foo: ["bar", "baz"]} will be serialized as “foo[]=bar&foo[]=baz”.

In jQuery 1.3, {foo: ["bar", "baz"]} was serialized as “foo=bar&foo=baz”. However, there was no way to encode a single-element Array using this approach. If you need the old behavior, you can turn it back on by setting the traditional Ajax setting (globally via jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional or on a case-by-case basis via the traditional flag).